# creating a method for regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to call a method. Method should do is find get the numbers stored at the string. This number is line a ID number for my backend db purpose. Now, whenever this method is called it should remove number including "-" which is added at the starting of that number and should also remove "Message:  ".

Below is my code which I am trying to run.

```
public void RegexMatch()
 {
   string pat = @"-{1,}[0-9]*$";
   Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 }

string void Main(strings[] args)
{
  String myLine = "Message:  Data have been confirmed -564673154463";
  if (myLine.StartWith("Message: "))
  {
    myLine = myLine.Replace("Message: ", "");
    myLine = RegexMatch()// replacing numbers with blank    
  }
}
```

Original Code:

```
String myLine = "Message: You Data is confirmed -564673154463";
if (myLine.StartsWith("Message"))
{
    string pat = @"-{1,}[0-9]*$";
    Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match m = r.Match(myLine);
    myLine = myLine.Replace("Message: ", "");
    myLine = r.Replace(myLine, "");
    string output = myLine.TrimStart();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

**Question**
**What am I missing in RegexMatch() which will help me to call that method?**

Can anyone help me with this? If anyone didn't understood any part please post question in this to get clarification.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean.  The code posted won't even compile, because you're trying to assign a `void` method result to a variable.  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Are you looking for `Regex.Replace`?

Comment: your method is void and returns nothing `public void RegexMatch()` so that's your first problem.. change the method signature to `string` and return return `r in your RegExMatch` method if `r` is of type string

Comment: `string void` makes no sense and `StartWith` doesn't exist (missing 's').

Comment: @Andrew Startwith check the condition if line starts with **Message: ** then do the below condition. 's' i didn't get it.

Comment: The method is `StartsWith`, so I guess you didn't copy this from Visual Studio. Did you try Dmitry's solution?

Comment: Please check my updated description.

Comment: May I know what am I missing that you guys put me onhold. What part is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the simplest approach to be used throughout your application, you can create an extension method like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string RemoveNumbers(this string source)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(source, "-?[0-9]+", "").Trim();
    }
}
```

And then you call it simply like this:

```
String myLine = "Message:  Data have been confirmed -564673154463";
if (myLine.StartsWith("Message: "))
{
    myLine = myLine.Replace("Message: ", "");
    myLine = myLine.RemoveNumbers();
}
Console.WriteLine(myLine);
```

I also called `Trim()` to remove any possible remaining space, like the one before "Data".

You may want to create a method that does the whole logic instead of only the `Regex` part, if that's what you will actually use repeatedly in your application. For example:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetMessage(this string source)
    {
        if (source.StartsWith("Message: "))
        {
            source = source.Replace("Message: ", "");
            source = Regex.Replace(source, "-?[0-9]+", "").Trim();
        }
        return source;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String myLine = "Message:  Data have been confirmed -564673154463";
        Console.WriteLine(myLine.GetMessage());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Please note that it's `static void Main`, and not `string void Main`.

Comment: getting an error at `RemoveNumbers();`

Comment: That comment doesn't help. Why didn't you specify the error? Note that the extension method must be in a separate class.

Comment: `'string does not contain for 'Removenumbers' and no extension method 'RemoveNumbers' accepting first argument of type 'string' couble be found.` yes I did it in seperate class

Comment: You must be missing something, are they sharing the namespace? I added more code in my answer, you can copy and paste the whole block in the same file and it must work. After that, it's a good idea to move the extension methods to a separate file.

Comment: Yes I did missed something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace numbers, well, just *replace*:

```
  String source = "Message:  Data have been confirmed -564673154463";
  String result = Regex.Replace(source, "-?[0-9]+", "");
```

please, notice that I've changed the pattern: `{,1}` is just `?` and `*` in the `[0-9]*` means that single `-` is a *number*, so I've changed `*` into `+`.